# Centering elements vertically in a fixed-height container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a website that needs a pixel based navbar - in this case `height: 80px`.

The problem is, I can't center the `ul` and `li` elements vertically.

I've tried using: `top:50%; transform: translate(0,-50%)`, as shown in my jsfiddle, and also flex positioning, but none have worked.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agreyfield91/w3s8cj92/

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-down">
  <nav class="headernav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Gig</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: All you need is to add `position: relative; overflow: hidden;` to the `nav ul` rule. The `position: relative;` to make transform work and `overflow: hidden;` to make it take height from its children (which is floated and need to be cleared). [**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/w3s8cj92/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add display flex and align-self center: https://jsfiddle.net/w3s8cj92/1/

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  align-self: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-down">
  <nav class="headernav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Gig</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add `position: relative` to `nav` and `position: absolute` to `nav ul` (to get `top: 50%; transform: translate(0,-50%);` to work) or you can just use `display: flex; align-items: center` on `nav`. I would just use flexbox.

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-down">
  <nav class="headernav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Gig</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your code could be much simpler:

```css
nav {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   /* horizontal alignment of child elements (optional) */
  background-color: bisque;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;      /* vertical alignment of text */
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

a + a {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Gig</a>
  <a href="#">ity</a>
  <a href="#">element</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I added borders around the links to show the clickable area, which is the entire height of the header. Other answers here just cover the text. Not sure which way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

In cases when you have static height of block, it is possible to center elements with no-wrap container with vertically in middle aligned inline[-block] elements.

```css
.vertical-container {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* this prevents vertical block to "fall out" of container */
}

.vertical-aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.vertical-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: normal;
  /* reset white-space for content */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-container"><span class="vertical-aligner"></span><span class="vertical-content">Text that should be vertically middle of container</span></div>
```

I have updated your fiddle accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/w3s8cj92/2/

P.S. I would like to provide more information, but later

Answer (score 0):

CSS Replace

```
header {
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
nav {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 80px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Here changes header css and nav ul css its work fine